# Is "and all" a filler?

Tags: meaning-in-context, colloquialisms

In L.P.Hartley's "The Go-between", one of the characters says

> "I didn't think I would find anyone here, being a Sunday and all."

In the 2002 English film "All or Nothing", a woman says:

> "I'm very lonely".

Her husband replies:

> "Me and all."

Is "and all" just a filler with no meaning whatever ?  Is it used only in England ?

Comment: My gut instinct is to say I think it probably is primarily British (but not just in *England*, please! :). It's certainly not a "filler", but it can almost always be directly replaced with the word **too**.

Comment: Not to be confusec with the Irish 'at all, at all'!

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the seconde example, replacement with the word "too" makes sense.

Comment: @Luis: There's absolutely no question but that your second example is an instance of the [British?] colloquial usage where it means *only and exactly* **too, also, as well**. I don't know the exact context of your first example, so I can't say whether that's the same, or whether it matches the more "literal" sense given by Susan.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The first example is said as part of an apology by a working man, when the members of the rich Family he worked for, find him taking a dip at their pool on a hot Sunday afternoon. (if they do have that in England).

Comment: @Luis: By "context", I meant the exact words of a reasonable amount of preceding and following text. That to me is the only way to establish whether the speaker might reasonably have used ***too*** there (perhaps because there'd already been mention of some *other* reason why he didn't expect anyone to be around). But apparently either Google Books doesn't have the full text of "The Go-between", or you've slightly misquoted. Whatever - I can't find the text, but it's not really important. Suffice it to say *either meaning could apply*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I tried to find my copy of "The Go-between", which I read in 1969, but it's gone.  Lord knows where.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The sentences in brackets are not from the book.(The Maudsleys and their guests are going to bathe in a pool within their property when they see a man swimming in it. )   "This place is private", he said to us. That man shouldn't be here".  (later, when the guy gets out of the water he tries to apologize for being there)  "I didn't know that you would be here," he said.  "The harvest has just started and I was very hot.  I thought I'd have a dip being a Sunday and all.

Comment: @Luis: You misunderstand me. I didn't mean "Give me a couple more sentences and I'll give you a definitive answer". Sure - it might make a difference whether the guy said *"I didn't think I would find anyone here"* or *"I thought I'd have a dip"* immediately before the words under consideration. But it might make a difference if we'd been told in an earlier chapter that he normally goes swimming somewhere else on Sunday because that's his day off. Or that agricultural labourers in the area routinely work so hard during the harvest they don't get to wash as often as they might like...

Comment: As a point of note, the usage in "The Go-betweens" is common in the US as well. I tend to interpret that as being the shortened version of "*and all that that implies*".  But I've never heard "Me and all" to mean "me too"- that sounds wrong to me, but I'd well believe it could be right in some other dialect.

Answer (score 1):

*I didn't think I would find anyone here, being a Sunday* **and all.**

**And all** is not a filler. It means *and all that is associated with the fact (that it is a Sunday)*. It means people usually do other things on Sundays because of all *Sunday* implies/carries with it.

> It being a Sunday and all, I'm sharing some thoughts on faith.
>   I would imagine it being a Sunday and all, most people are headed back to their homes and getting ready for the workweek.

The second usage is potentially totally different. It may be *you, me, and everyone else* or might mean *because of me and all that implies*. Without more context, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Are those examples real citations, or just made up for the purposes of illustration? I think in OP's L.P.Hartley excerpt, **and all** is used to mean **too**, which imho is the normal sense. There's some "crossover" with the possibility of it being used to mean **and all that that implies** (because it's Sunday, there are various "triggers" that encourage me to think about religious faith and share my thoughts with others). Personally, I'd be likely to use **and all that** if I intended that sense.

Comment: When I make things us, I say so.

Comment: It was a genuine enquiry, not a criticism that needed to be robustly rebuffed. So is this, so don't bite again! :) Why don't you include links when citing text that others might wish to evaluate in a more complete context?

Comment: I'd say the second example just means “me too”, since that's what “me and all” usually means when spoken in isolation (at least in my experience). That places the quote as BrE, of course, but then we already know it's from an English movie,

Comment: @Janus: Yeah - I just checked OED. There's a lot to wade through under **all**, even when I'm only interested in the 117 instances of "and all". But eventually I got to *colloq. and regional **(chiefly Sc.)**. Used at the end of a sentence, clause, etc., for emphasis: ‘also’, ‘too’, ‘as well’. Also used adverbially: ‘really’, ‘truly’, ‘indeed’.* So it's definitely BrE, but apparently not "Sarf London", as I originally suspected.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I probably link my answers more than 99% of users here; sometimes I don't feel like it. I was neither robust nor toothy. I meant what I said. If you want the link, copy and past it into google; you'll see it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd like to hear what you would say about this.  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169795/what-is-the-vocative-expression-we-can-use-to-attract-the-attention-of-someone-w  Would you mind ?

Comment: @Luis: *"I dunno, **man**"*. It seems to me "vocative expression" isn't really what you're looking for when you want a generic attention-grabbing term. Whilst it's true that in some contexts I might say *"I don't know, sir/ma'am"*, in less formal contexts I might use *man, pal, mate, chum, kiddo, laddie, etc.*. But *"Man! You dropped your wallet!"* doesn't work at all so far as I'm concerned - in *that* context you'd have to say *"**Hey**, man! You dropped your wallet!"*.